# SSH config file in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

I'm looking for a way to use the `ssh_config` files in Windows, and I know in Linux it's located at `~/.ssh/config`.

Where is the Windows location and is there any difference in syntax or paths used inside the file?

Comment: Use SSH config with which software? On Linux the SSH library  (which is the code that uses the config file) is shared between apps, but on Windows, you are a likely to have different SSH implementations and different configurations.

Comment: @xenoid I'm using Powershell's Win32-Openssh: [link](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/v8.1.0.0p1-Beta)

Comment: And also, I'd like to use this config file, for hosts: [link](https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/)

Comment: User-specific client config is the same as in Linux, within the user's home directory (Powershell: `~\.ssh\config`; Explorer: `%UserProfile%\.ssh\config`), whereas the system-wide client `ssh_config` would be located at `%ProgramData%\ssh\ssh_config`, along with the `sshd_config` server config. Syntax is the same in all files, however the option parameters for file paths and subsystems is different ([examples](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH/Windows)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a config file at `%UserProfile%\.ssh\config`. I don't have a source for this, but it works for SSH connections in PowerShell and remote connections within Visual Studio Code.

I don't think OpenSSH config in Windows 10 differs from Linux in terms of syntax; I've copied and pasted configs from Windows 10 to WSL and to native Linux machines with no issues.

Comment: It worked, thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

According to
[OpenSSH Server Configuration for Windows 10 1809 and Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration):

> In Windows, sshd reads configuration data from `%programdata%\ssh\sshd_config` by default

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't fully specific: I want to use the one like this: [link](https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/)

Comment: My linked article is for Powershell. It also says that you may use a non-default config file by setting it in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH`.

Comment: @harrymc OpenSSH has three default config files - user-specific _(`%UserProfile%\.ssh\config`)_ and system-wide _(`%ProgramData%\ssh\ssh_config`)_ [client configs](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) and a system-wide _(`%ProgramData%\ssh\sshd_config`)_ [server config](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config); the same is true for BSD/Linux, just at different locations _(`~/.ssh/config`, `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)_. If the user-specific client config is present, it supersedes the system-wide client config.